# SQL COLUMN NAME

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports

I'm working with JASPERREPORT, I have to create an SQL Query to have the right report
I have tow tables in my databases like :

```
**Columns**:

|Column's numbre |column's description |
|----------------|---------------------|
| 1              | X                   |
| 2              | Y                   |
| 3              | Z                   |

**Tableau**:
|LINE.NUMBRE   |COLUMN.NUMBRE   |CELLE.CONTENT|
|--------------|----------------|------------ |
| 1            | 1              |A            |
| 1            | 2              |B            |
| 1            | 3              |C            |
| 2            | 1              |D            |
| 2            | 2              |E            |
| 2            | 3              |F            |
```

And in my report I want to have this Table

```
|  X  |  Y  |  Z  |
|-----|-----|-----|
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
|  D  |  E  |  F  |
```

I tried this QUERY:

```
SELECT F_ROW_LABEL1, F_ROW_LABEL2, F_ROW_LABEL3
FROM   
        (SELECT T.LIGNE_NUMBRE , T.COLUMN_NUMBRE, T.CELL_CONTENT
                    FROM   TABLEAU T , COLUMNS C
                    WHERE  --Conditions
                            AND C.COLUMN_NUMBRE= T.COLUMN_NUMBRE
            )
PIVOT  (CELL_CONTENT FOR (COLUMN_NUMBRE)  IN (1 AS F_ROW_LABEL1, 2 AS F_ROW_LABEL2, 3 AS F_ROW_LABEL3))
```

And I have this result:

```
|F_ROW_LABEL1| F_ROW_LABEL2| F_ROW_LABEL3|
|------------|-------------|-------------|
|  A         |  B          |  C          |
|  D         |  E          |  F          |
```

The rest is how can I return the column's header from my query.

Thanks,

Comment: [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)